# Find coordinates in MKCoordinateRegion

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkmapview

I have a list of places with their coordinates (latitude + longitude).

I want to get only the places that are in the region displayed on the screen.

I can get the current region displayed on my screen with: 
`MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D, span: MKCoordinateSpan)`

However I don't know under which parameters I should filter the coordinates of my list to only get the places in this region. 
MKCoordinateSpan isn't convertible into a distance mesure from the center.

Thanks for helping

Comment: If I understand right, the center will exactly in the middle of the number of each parameters of the span, is that right ?

Comment: However, I think the simplest way is actually to convert to MKMapRect and MKMapPoint.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest way is to get the displayed region as an MKMapRect with `visibleMapRect` and convert your coordinates to MKMapPoint using the `MKMapPoint(_:)` initializer. That way you can just call MKMapRect `contains(_:)`.